# Hello, I am having a problem in my python code. I am a beginner so this in a really simple ask

Tags: python

I am having a problem in my python code. I am a beginner so this in a really simple ask. So I only have some months experience(4 months). I am making a project in which there are QnA(s) I am having problem with 2 things. First: I am not able to call these functions:

```
def questions() 

def question2()
```

Second problem: I want to make options for the questions for E.G:

```
def question():


    Q1 = input("Who is the lord of a random place")
    if Q1 == ["Lofi", "Loafer", "Lofe"]:
        print('Correct answer!!')
    else:
        print('Wrong answer!! The correct answer is LOFI!!')
```

I am not sure what operator or keyword to use to do this. Please help, Here is the Code:

```
def question():


    Q1 = input("Who is the lord of a random place")
    if Q1 == ["Lofi", "Loafer", "Lofe"]:
        print('Correct anwer!!')
    else:
        print('Wrong answer!! The correct answer is LOFI!!')
    question() 
def question2():
    Q2 = input("Who is the most trustful person in the world?")
    if Q2 == ["Lofi", "Annu", "scoob"]:
        print("Correct answer!! U WIN!!!!")
    else:
        print("WRONG ANSWER!!")
    question2()
```

Comment: Try `if Q1 in [...]`

Answer (score 0):

How are you?
To call a function you should do this =>  myfunction()

You don't need to put a word def before your function when you want to call your function.
To call functions try this code :

```
questions()
question2()
```

For your second question I don't understand that

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to indent the program correctly . Call to the functions  question() and question2() needs to be in the root indent
2. You can either check the string is present in a list by using "in" keyword as in question function , or use keyword "any" as in the question2 function

   ```
   def question():
     Q1 = input("Who is the lord of a random place")
     if Q1 in ["Lofi", "Loafer", "Lofe"]:
        print('Correct anwer!!')
     else:
        print('Wrong answer!! The correct answer is LOFI!!')


   def question2():
     Q2 = input("Who is the most trustful person in the world?")
     Ans =  ["Lofi", "Loafer", "Lofe"]
     if any(Q2 in item for item in Ans):
        print("Correct answer!! U WIN!!!!")
     else:
        print("WRONG ANSWER!!")

   question() 

   question2()
   ```